# Cache network commands

Tags: linux, download, cache

I have the following situation:

I need to install software in a singularity container which fails at several points. Every time it fails, I need to restart the building process.

Then, it will re-download a lot of stuff which takes lots of time.

Is there any command or possibility to create a command, such that I can enter:

```
cachenetwork singularity build ...
```

and then `cachenetwork` grabs all the download-requests, downloads them if they're not already downloaded and caches them, and if already downloaded, returns the files from the local filesystem, acting as if it was downloaded by the original URL?

So, for example, singularity tries to download `https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-9-2_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb` and at first, it just downloads the file and returns it. And the second time when accessing the URL, it will return the content of e.g. `.cache/networkcache/$(md5sum https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-9-2_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb)/cuda-9-2_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb`.

This should be possible to do. But I do not know how to this. Is it possible to do that without setting up a complex proxy?

This would be really helpful.

Comment: No matter how you manage to do it, it won't be simpler than setting up a proxy. Which is easy if you already run containers: Just deploy a second container that contains the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think you got the complexity assessment the wrong way around. Actually telling a program to send requests there is far simpler than magically intercepting connections.

#### Implementing 'cachenetwork'

Programs **do not actually make** such "download requests" to the OS – they only ask the OS to open the underlying TCP connection, but then speak the HTTP protocol entirely on their own. The OS isn't aware of the URLs being requested (really it doesn't even know whether the connection is being used for HTTP or not).

So your first issue is that there's no easy API to detect what's being downloaded – after figuring out how to make the OS redirect all connections through your tool (e.g. using iptables "tproxy"), you need to actually interpret those HTTP requests yourself (as if you were the server) and provide spoofed responses.

That's actually *exactly* what a proxy does. If you wrote such a tool, you would just end up writing an HTTP proxy in everything but name. (Most existing HTTP proxy software can provide caching for you, and some of them even have tproxy integration aka "transparent proxy" mode.)

The second problem is that because your builder actually downloads some files from **HTTPS** sites (instead of plaintext http://), the entire contents of the TCP connection are encrypted, and the HTTP request details are *only* visible to the program. Yes, SSL/TLS is *also* handled by the program itself, and even the local OS is unable to decrypt the data.

So not only you'd need to act as a fake HTTP server, you'd also need to act as a fake SSL/TLS server – and the programs would notice, because the whole point of "certificates" in SSL/TLS is to make this impossible.

(Of course, you can still make it work on *your own* system either by disabling host verification, or by issuing your own certificates and marking them as locally trusted. And that feature too can be found in some existing HTTP proxy software.)

I guess various bits like this are what *makes* proxies seem complex.

#### Caching `apt` packages

In addition to generic caching HTTP proxies, there are programs specifically meant for caching Apt package downloads, such as [apt-cacher-ng](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/05/05/using-apt-cacher-ng-with-ssl-tls/).

If used as an ordinary proxy, they'll still have exactly the same problem with HTTPS as any other proxy. However, as the linked article shows, as long as you can *change the repository URL* in apt's `source.list`, it is possible to "remap" it and make it cacheable even though HTTPS is in use. So you'll only need to find where Singularity stores its `download.nvidia.com` root URL.